# Bin Packing Optimization Best Fit

Tags: algorithm, optimization, cut, bin-packing

I have this Bin Packing code:

```
Public Class Cortar
    Private _Cortes() As Integer
    Public BarrasCortes()() As Integer
    Private _TamanhoBarra As Integer = 100

    Public Property TamanhoBarra() As Integer
        Get
            Return _TamanhoBarra
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            _TamanhoBarra = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Cortes() As Integer()
        Get
            Return _Cortes
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer())
            _Cortes = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub MelhorCorte()
        'Checks to make sure everything is initialized
        If Cortes Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Dim CortesCopy(Cortes.GetUpperBound(0)) As Integer
        ReDim BarrasCortes(0)
        'Bin Number we are on, Bin Element we are on, Amount placed in the current Bin
        Dim BinNumber, BinElement, BinCount As Integer
        Dim BestBin, BestBinAmount As Integer
        Dim i, j, k As Integer

        'Make a copy of the array incase we need to sort it
        DeepCopyArray(Cortes, CortesCopy)

        'Declare the first element in the first Bin
        ReDim BarrasCortes(0)(0)

        'Loop through each Element and place in a Bin
        For i = 0 To CortesCopy.GetUpperBound(0)
            BestBin = -1
            BestBinAmount = -1

            For j = 0 To BinNumber
                BinElement = BarrasCortes(j).GetUpperBound(0)

                'Count the amount placed in this Bin
                BinCount = 0
                For k = 0 To BinElement
                    BinCount += BarrasCortes(j)(k)
                Next

                'Find the most full Bin that can hold this Element
                If BestBinAmount < BinCount AndAlso BinCount + CortesCopy(i) <= Me.TamanhoBarra Then
                    BestBinAmount = BinCount
                    BestBin = j
                End If
            Next


            If BestBin = -1 Then
                'There wasn't room for the Element in any existing Bin
                'Create a new Bin
                ReDim Preserve BarrasCortes(BinNumber + 1)
                BinNumber += 1

                'Initialize first element of new bin
                ReDim BarrasCortes(BinNumber)(1)
                BinElement = 0

                BarrasCortes(BinNumber)(BinElement) = CortesCopy(i)
            Else
                'There's room for this Element in an existing Bin
                'Place Element in "Best Bin"
                BinElement = BarrasCortes(BestBin).GetUpperBound(0)
                ReDim Preserve BarrasCortes(BestBin)(BinElement + 1)
                BarrasCortes(BestBin)(BinElement) = CortesCopy(i)
            End If
        Next

        'All Cortes have been place, now we go back and remove unused Cortes
        For i = 0 To BinNumber
            For j = 0 To BarrasCortes(i).GetUpperBound(0)
                If BarrasCortes(i)(j) = 0 Then
                    ReDim Preserve BarrasCortes(i)(j - 1)
                End If
            Next
        Next

        GC.Collect()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeepCopyArray(ByVal ArrayStart() As Integer, ByVal ArrayEnd() As Integer)
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To ArrayStart.GetUpperBound(0)
            ArrayEnd(i) = ArrayStart(i)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

This works fine, but have a problem:

If I define, in C#:

```
var obj= new Cortar();
obj.TamanhoBarra = 100;
obj.Cortes = new int[] {48, 48, 26, 26};
obj.MelhorCorte();
int[][] x = obj.BarrasCortes;
```

The result is:

```
x[0] = {48,48} //rest 4 to 100 (TamanhoBarra)
x[1] = {26,26} //rest 48 to 100 (TamanhoBarra)
```

But if I just change the order of elements in array to

```
obj.Cortes = new int[] {48, 26, 48, 26};
```

The result will be:

```
x[0] = {48,26,26} //rest 0 to 100 (TamanhoBarra) = best optimization
x[1] = {48} //rest 52 to 100 (TamanhoBarra)
```

The problem is:

How do the best optmization for bar?

Best opmitization is the sum of elements until max size with the less rest.

In the above situation is easy.

But if I have:

```
obj.Cortes = new int[] {48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26 };
```

The result will be:

```
x[0] = {48,48} //rest 4
x[1] = {48,48} //rest 4
x[2] = {48,48} //rest 4
x[3] = {48,48} //rest 4
x[4] = {48,48} //rest 4
x[5] = {26,26,26} //rest 22
x[6] = {26,26,26} //rest 22
x[7] = {26,26,26} //rest 22
x[8] = {26} //rest 74
```

Many bar and total loss

But if I arrange the array like this:

```
obj.Cortes = new int[] {48, 26, 26, 48, 26, 26, 48, 26, 26, 48, 26, 26, 48, 26, 26, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48 };
```

The result is:

```
x[0] = {48,26,26} //rest 0
x[1] = {48,26,26} //rest 0
x[2] = {48,26,26} //rest 0
x[3] = {48,26,26} //rest 0
x[4] = {48,26,26} //rest 0
x[5] = {48,48} //rest 4
x[6] = {48,48} //rest 4
x[7] = {48} //rest 52
```

This is the best solutiuon!

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bin Packing - Brute force recursive solution - How to make it faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310385/bin-packing-brute-force-recursive-solution-how-to-make-it-faster)

Answer (score 0):

With small numbers of item you can try all possibility. Then you can try a dynamic programming.

Comment: I'm sorry if you don't understand the answer. Is this homework?

Comment: No.... I need implemente a optmize cut bars in my work..... the above code works, but need be bester!!!

Comment: What code? Your code in your question? What is cut bars? Can you point me to a website?

Comment: yes, my code..... if I have bars of 100mm I can use this code to find how many cuts is possible until 100mm, for example if I need cut a bar of 100mm in cuts of 10, 10, 20, 30, 50 and 80, this code return: 1 bar {10,10,20,30} 1 bar{50} and 1 bar{80}... bar or bin.. is the same!

Comment: for mor information about my code: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/5540/bin-packing/